# Create VM from snapshot in Xen console

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

I have this snapshot:

```
# xe snapshot-list
uuid ( RO)                : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
          name-label ( RW): ubuntu_clean
    name-description ( RW):
    is-vmss-snapshot ( RO): false
```

How can I create a VM from it?

On Citrix web documentation, they explain how to do this in XenCenter, unfortunately nothing about xen console: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xencenter/6-2/xs-xc-vms/xs-xc-templates-new.html

I found an administration manual, that explains how commands work: https://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/7-1/downloads/xenserver-7-1-administrators-guide.pdf

Even with administration manual it was not clear for me how to create a VM from a snapshot.

Comment: This question does not show research effort. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @StefanCrain, thank you for your answer. I want to understand why did you say this. Did I say something not clearly, or incomplete?

Comment: No problem, I suggested you review the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide above, [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2730283) is also a good read for understanding what makes a well researched question.

Comment: Well, the manual didn't show clearly that we can use snapshots identification as template identification. This is why I created this question and answer by myself. I read MCVE and I did some changes on question. I don't see how to enhance more. If still no ok, let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snapshots in the same way of templates, so snapshot name and uuid are valid to `xe vm-install`.

So, you have two options available:

```
# xe vm-install template=ubuntu_clean new-name-label=my_new_vm
00000000-1111-1111-1111-000000000000

# xe vm-install template-uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 new-name-label=my_new_vm_2
00000000-2222-2222-2222-000000000000
```

It will return VM hash.